# UIImageView+AFNetworking fails to load image in aeroplane mode?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I use AFNetworking to load RSS.
It appears that the HTTP request to the RSS is cached in disk successfully.
Even if aeroplane mode, the RSS can still be displayed.

But for the images url in the RSS, I used UIImageView+AFNetworking category to load, they fail to be loaded if the phone is in offline mode...why?

This is how i init SDURLCache:

```
  // configure the disk cache here
    self.cache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024 // 1 MB mem cache
                                                         diskCapacity:1024*1024*5 // 5 MB disk cache
                                                             diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];    
    self.cache.ignoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy = YES;
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:self.cache];
```

This is the code to load the images.

```
[self setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail_loading.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `cache.ignoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy = YES`. If images are ever loaded, they should be persisted on disk with this setting.

Comment: hi matt, I tried that setting already. It is the same. I found out that, what happen is this: The app load an image at 3pm. The header says it expires in 3 hrs. at 5pm, run app in offline mode, AFnetworking will return the cached copy. At 7pm, run app in offline mode again, cached content expired, AFnetworking will throw an exception because it failed to revalidate the content with the server. There is a question about this issue raised by another person here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250055/sdurlcache-with-afnetworking-and-offline-mode-not-working#comment13872477_10250055