# Offline mode using NSURLCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking-2, nsurlcache

I am using AFNetworking with NSURLCache. Requests are created with `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`. App receives responses with headers:

```
Etag = "1398684731";
Cache-Control = "public";
```

and everything works perfect. But now I need to add an offline mode.

How it should work:

- If internet connection is available everything should work as usual
  (application asks back-end for new data and if it has different
  `Etag` new data is downloaded if `Etag` is the same - cached response
  is used).
- If there is no internet connection - cached response is
  used.

The problem is that in offline mode requests fail.

I have tried to solve this using various `Cache-Control` options but it seems that it does not work this way.

I have found possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885318/3140927 . It should work but it is not very elegant and I think something might have changed in the last year.

Also I have found that "NSURLCache was not made for explicit offline scenarios and that it was designed to speed up Safari and should not be used for manual downloads". Will SDURLCache be better for my purposes?

So what could be the best way to implement offline mode?

Comment: I think the URL itself solves your problem, you should use SDURLCache and AFNetworking since you can easily modify it, or, it you don't want to use AFNetworking you can write your own NSURLConnection class, but since we have `AFNetworking` and solution we should switch to it

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the request to succeed, even though the cache says the data has expired and should be retrieved from the server. You may have some luck setting the cache policy (different policy for online vs. offline) of certain requests where you'd rather use stale data than fail.

**Great Link is here**->
[SDURLCache with AFNetworking and offline mode not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250055/sdurlcache-with-afnetworking-and-offline-mode-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, I have the same link in my question. What I want - is to emulate custom cache policy. Something like "NSURLRequest_TryToLoad_ElseUseCache".

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried to solve exactly the same problem with this article and it works pretty well: http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/. The key point is here to subclass NSURLCache to make your cache independent from response headers.

I've found couple mistypes in examples, but hope it still will be helpful for you!

Comment: The link is broken.